# XA Datasource and cockpit

Tags: mysql, mybatis, camunda

I use two XA Datasources into a EAP7 and MySQL. The application is running, but after call of the cockpit a lot of exceptions are thrown. Camunda in Version 7.5

The configuration is the same for both. (Generated by Red Hat EAP Docker Image)

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine"
    pool-name="eap_app_mysql-DB" use-java-context="true" enabled="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">12.345.678.90</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Port">3306</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">processengine</xa-datasource-property>
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>username</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
            <valid-connection-checker
                class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
            <exception-sorter
                class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
        </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

I tried to shorten the log and paste the complete here https://hastebin.com/safegezoxo.hs

```
[org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (default task-91) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@6de438d4[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1487744241500 lastValidated=1487744110263 lastCheckedOut=1487744241705 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3de504bf mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@199913f6[pool=eap_app_mysql-DB] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@4da0c70d[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.16 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine] txSync=TransactionSynchronization@1199406255{tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0ac006d8:-7ec69b48:58ac47a3:84f52 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING > wasTrackByTx=true enlisted=false cancel=false}]: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAException: XAER_OUTSIDE: Some work is done outside global transaction
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: XAER_OUTSIDE: Some work is done outside global transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAConnection.dispatchCommand(MysqlXAConnection.java:562)
    ... 99 more
[com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-91) ARJUNA016061: TransactionImple.enlistResource - XAResource.start returned: XAException.XAER_OUTSIDE for < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=43, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0ac006d8:-7ec69b48:58ac47a3:84f52, node_name=eap-app-4-wxyq3, branch_uid=0:ffff0ac006d8:-7ec69b48:58ac47a3:84f54, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine >: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAException: XAER_OUTSIDE: Some work is done outside global transaction
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@6de438d4[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1487744241500 lastValidated=1487744110263 lastCheckedOut=1487744241705 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3de504bf mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@199913f6[pool=eap_app_mysql-DB] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@4da0c70d[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.16 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine] txSync=null]
### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/ProcessDefinition.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntity.selectProcessDefinition
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@6de438d4[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1487744241500 lastValidated=1487744110263 lastCheckedOut=1487744241705 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3de504bf mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@199913f6[pool=eap_app_mysql-DB] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@4da0c70d[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.16 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine] txSync=null]: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@6de438d4[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1487744241500 lastValidated=1487744110263 lastCheckedOut=1487744241705 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3de504bf mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@199913f6[pool=eap_app_mysql-DB] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@4da0c70d[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.16 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine] txSync=null]
### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/ProcessDefinition.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntity.selectProcessDefinition
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@6de438d4[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1487744241500 lastValidated=1487744110263 lastCheckedOut=1487744241705 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3de504bf mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@199913f6[pool=eap_app_mysql-DB] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@4da0c70d[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@53389a35 pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.16 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine] txSync=null]
```

Comment: Which version of the Mysql JDBC Driver do you use?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-3.el7.noarch from Red hat repo.I have also tried the most recent from the MySQL site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the datasource factory and the result works without problems:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine"
    pool-name="eap_app_mysql-DB" use-java-context="true" enabled="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">IP</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Port">PORT</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">processengine</xa-datasource-property>
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>username</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
        <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
        <xa-pool>
            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>60</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>false</prefill>
            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
            <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
            <wrap-xa-resource>true</wrap-xa-resource>
         </xa-pool>
         <validation>
            <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
            <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
         </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```